# Reordering the data in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have report data is that structured as followed:

```
RecID | ReportView1           | Name    | Value | Total 
1     | CURRENT_VIEW          | 'Test1' | 10    | 20
1     | PROPOSED_VIEW         | 'Test11'| 20    | 30
1     | POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW | null    | null  | 80
2     | CURRENT_VIEW          | 'Test1' | 10    | 20
2     | PROPOSED_VIEW         | 'Test22'| 25    | 35
2     | POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW | null    | null  | 70
3     | CURRENT_VIEW          | 'Test1' | 10    | 20
3     | PROPOSED_VIEW         | 'Test33'| 45    | 65
3     | POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW | null    | null  | 90
```

I want to reorder based on TOTAL DECS but only apply for ReportView1 = 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW '

So the data will be:

```
NewRecID | RecID | ReportView1           | Name     | Value | Total 
1        | 3     | CURRENT_VIEW          | 'Test1'  | 10    | 20
1        | 3     | PROPOSED_VIEW         | 'Test33' | 45    | 65
1        | 3     | POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW | null     | null  | 90
2        | 1     | CURRENT_VIEW          | 'Test1'  | 10    | 20
2        | 1     | PROPOSED_VIEW         | 'Test11' | 20    | 30
2        | 1     | POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW | null     | null  | 80
3        | 2     | CURRENT_VIEW          | 'Test1'  | 10    | 20
3        | 2     | PROPOSED_VIEW         | 'Test22' | 25    | 35
3        | 2     | POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW | null     | null  | 70
```

I could probably use joining withiin itself BUT I am just wondering it may be there is  an alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Edited to account for cases with duplicate totals.)*

```
;
WITH atable (RecID , ReportView1   , Name    , Value , Total) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'CURRENT_VIEW         ', 'Test1' , 10    , 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'PROPOSED_VIEW        ', 'Test11', 20    , 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW', null    , null  , 80 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'CURRENT_VIEW         ', 'Test1' , 10    , 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'PROPOSED_VIEW        ', 'Test22', 25    , 35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW', null    , null  , 70 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'CURRENT_VIEW         ', 'Test1' , 10    , 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'PROPOSED_VIEW        ', 'Test33', 45    , 65 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW', null    , null  , 90 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'CURRENT_VIEW         ', 'Test1' , 10    , 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'PROPOSED_VIEW        ', 'Test11', 20    , 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW', null    , null  , 80
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = MAX(CASE ReportView1 WHEN 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW' THEN Total END)
          OVER (PARTITION BY RecID)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  NewRecID = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rnk DESC, RecID),
  RecID,
  ReportView1,
  Name,
  Value,
  Total
FROM ranked
ORDER BY
  rnk DESC,
  RecID,
  Total
```

Output:

```
NewRecID  RecID  ReportView1            Name    Value  Total
--------  -----  ---------------------  ------  -----  -----
1         3      CURRENT_VIEW           Test1   10     20
1         3      PROPOSED_VIEW          Test33  45     65
1         3      POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW  NULL    NULL   90
2         1      CURRENT_VIEW           Test1   10     20
2         1      PROPOSED_VIEW          Test11  20     30
2         1      POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW  NULL    NULL   80
3         4      CURRENT_VIEW           Test1   10     20
3         4      PROPOSED_VIEW          Test11  20     30
3         4      POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW  NULL    NULL   80
4         2      CURRENT_VIEW           Test1   10     20
4         2      PROPOSED_VIEW          Test22  25     35
4         2      POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW  NULL    NULL   70
```

Comment: +1 I prefer these solutions without the use of joins. This would more or less have been the same solution i would have come up with.

Comment: Hi there ... I found some anomaly, if The total for each POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW are the same it causing an issue. Can we put some extra RecID as another sort.

Comment: @dcalliances: Yes, adding `RecID` to the main SELECT's `ORDER BY` clause (between `rnk DESC` and `Total`) as well as to the `ORDER BY` clause of the ranking function (after `rnk DESC`) seems to fix the issue. (Updated my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
with OrderedTable as (
  select recid, total orderedTotal from t1
  where reportview1 = 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW'
)
select t1.* from OrderedTable o
join t1 on o.recid = t1.recid
order by o.orderedTotal desc, t1.total
```

Or without CTE:

```
select t1.* from (
  select recid, total orderedTotal from t1
  where reportview1 = 'POTENTIAL_SAVING_VIEW'
) o
join t1 on o.recid = t1.recid
order by o.orderedTotal desc, t1.total
```

Note each group of Recs is being ordered by total ASC, which is how I guess you want them displayed (based on provided example)

Comment: nice but don't you want to add something to control ordering within each group so it goes "current / proposed /potential"... for completeness?

Comment: Good point! Just added a sub-order on total, which seems to be the column on which the group of recids is being ordered